# When referring to another clause, is the non-relative clause always singular?

Tags: clauses, independent-clauses

I have seen examples in some grammar website about non-relative clauses that refer to the whole main clause:

> Chris did really well in his exams, which is quite a surprise.
>
> My friends were all hiding in my apartment, which isn't what I'd
>   expected.
>
> She's studying to become a doctor, which is difficult.

I notice the non-relative clauses are all in singular forms but I am not sure if that's the rule.

Comment: I love the local bananas, which are very sweet.

Comment: @WS2 in this case, the clause refers to *bananas* not the whole main clause

Comment: Chris did really well in his exams, and he's planning to become a doctor, both of which were a surprise to me.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thanks. So using singular form or plural form is up to how many clauses the non-relative clause refers to?

Comment: So it seems. There might be more to it, but I don't know of any rule; I just thought of that example.

Comment: The clause that is referring to another clause refers to one thing: the clause. Unless there is more than one clause to which this clause refers, it is necessarily singular as per the regular pluralisation rules.

Comment: *It was a strange company to work for: when time was of the essence, things took longer, which surprised me.*  The number of preceding clauses is not the determining factor, it's whether the preceding clause or clauses form a single idea that can be referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *which-clauses* in your example sentences ( *... which is quite a surprise, ... which isn't what I'd expected, ... which is difficult*) are indeed relative clauses, not non-relative clauses.

*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p1118) refers to such evaluative or comment clauses as *sentential relative clauses*. For *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1034) they are one type of *supplementary relative clause*.

The antecedent of these relative clauses is the information in the preceding clause (or indeed in a longer chunk of preceding text) in its singular entirety. For this reason, the  verb in the relative clause is in the singular form.

*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* has the following example, where the sentential relative clause refers to two antecedent clauses:

> Colin married my sister and I married his brother, which **makes** Colin
>   and me double-in-laws.

Of course, it is possible for a sentential relative clause to contain a plural verb if there is a plural subject in that clause:

> Chris did really well in his exams, which Colin and I **find** quite a
>   surprise.